# Facebook SDK / free and paid iOS app : should I use one or two app IDs?

Tags: android, ios, facebook, facebook-sdk-4.0

I see that Facebook allows to create one Facebook App ID per application (same FB App ID for the iOS version, Android version, etc...).

My problem is that the iOS version of the app has 2 versions : 1 free version and 1 paid version.

In order to be able to use properly all the Facebook features (analytics, ads conversion tracking, login...) should I use one Facebook App ID for both iOS apps (free and paid) or two different FB app IDs ? (one for the free version and one for the paid version)

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use one Facebook App ID in both paid and free versions of your app, just add their Bundle IDs in Facebook Settings.

[Confirmation in Facebook's FAQ](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/troubleshooting/#faq_112617202494710)

Comment: Thanks. Question : how can I view the stats of the free and paid version separately in Facebook Analytics ? Thanks.

Comment: I don't see such a option in Facebook Analytics, there's only possibility to see stats separately for iOS and Android platforms. In this case, if you want to have separated statistics, I think that it'd be better to create a Facebook App per application.